# Package Manager vs. Git Submodule/Subtree

Tags: git, git-submodules, dependency-management, package-managers, git-subtree

Are there any reasons to use a package manager rather than git submodules/subtrees, or vice versa? The git solutions seem to be a lot more hassle than a simple package manager.

Assume that the space-saving benefit of git submodules is not important.

Comment: I think using some kind of package manager is simpler than git submodules/subtrees... dependencies in languages like C#(nuget), node(npm) or rust(cargo) are never copied, only file with dependency list is in the repo

Comment: I assume your question relates to C/C++ projects here?

Comment: @Konrad No, I was asking about package managers in general.

Comment: Regarding hassle, it can go either way. A package manager may actually be more work if your main goal is just to modularize your code base. You then have to deal with versioning each module.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> The git solutions seem to be a lot more hassle than a simple package manager.

This is not about *hassle*.

This is about two different ways to build a project:

1. through binary dependencies, with a package manager ([Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype), or [Conan for C++](https://conan.io/): you *declare* your dependencies, and the package manager fetches them and uses them during the compilation.
   That is what a **[`pom.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)** or a [`npm-package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json): just one more file within your unique codebase, which will instruct the compiler to download the relevant dependencies
2. through *source* dependencies, with Git submodules or subtrees, where you store references to other source code, import them, and recompile everything.
   For instance, if your system is composed of a front-end GUI sources and a backend sources, you could reference both repositories within one parent project repositories, combining their sources into one code base.

The first is good when building a system, where each part has its own release lifecycle, and you want to depend to pre-built dependencies.

The second is used when the dependencies are more tightly linked to the main program.

Or when there are no binary dependencies (which is the case, for instance, with [Go](https://golang.org/) and [its modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules)).

Comment: What do you mean by more tightly linked?

Comment: By binary dependencies you mean linking to pre-built static or dynamic libraries?

Comment: @Konrad "tightly linked" means: you cannot modify the main project without modifying the dependencies. Recompiling everything is, in that instance, best.

Comment: @Konrad yes, pre-built, meaning you can make many evolution to your project but would need the *same* dependencies: no need to recompile everything in that case. Pre-built artifacts are enough, and can be declared in a small text file, then fetched from an artifact repository, as I mention in the answer.

Comment: I actually didn't know that some package managers fetch packages during compilation itself! The only ones I've ever had experience with just add packages to the source the second you declare the dependencies.

Comment: @VonC could you please add examples for both scenes? not quite understand the differences and their application

Comment: @Steve Sure, I have edited the answer to include some links and examples.

Answer (score 21):

#### "If the technological context allows for packaging and formal dependency management, you should absolutely go this route."

The above is from [Mastering Git submodules](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-submodules-34c65e940407), which is such a well written and thought out article it deserves to be the top answer for this and many similar Stackoverflow questions.

Let me quote the part that is relevant to this question:

> ## Are they the right tool for the job?
>
> There are a number of situations where the physical presence of module code inside container code is mandated, usually because of the technology or framework being used. For instance, themes and plugins for Wordpress, Magento, etc. are often de facto installed by their mere presence at conventional locations inside the project tree, and this is the only way to “install” them.
>
> In such a situation, going with submodules (or subtrees) probably is the right solution, provided you do need to version that code and collaborate around it with third parties (or deploy it on another machine); for strictly local, unversioned situations, symbolic links are probably enough, but this is not what this post is about.
>
> On the other hand, if the technological context allows for packaging and formal dependency management, you should absolutely go this route instead: it lets you better split your codebase, avoid a number of side effects and pitfalls that litter the submodule space, and let you benefit from versioning schemes such as semantic versioning (semver) for your dependencies.

Comment: Answer is to the point and gives a nice link for further reading. thanks!

Comment: Careful about this article though, it is a bit dated and not everything written in it is still true. For example, `git pull` learned `--recurse-submodules` since it was written.

Comment: @philb of course, as will be the case for any article on shortcomings of git commands, as git evolves rather rapidly. But the argument it makes that answers the SO question above depends not at all on git flaws, but on fundamental differences between package managers and git submodules/subtrees. That won't change.