# How to remove a submodule going forward, but keep its history (as linked from parent history)?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Say I have a project that has a dependency implemented using `git submodule`. Now I'm making a change where this dependency is no longer needed. I want to commit a change that works as follows:

- If anyone checks out this commit or any descendants, the submodule doesn't exist.
- But if anyone checks out an older commit, or a commit on another branch not merged with this one, the submodule reappears, just as a deleted file would.
- The submodule's own git database (.git/modules/path/to/submodule) must be preserved as it may contain commits not pushed to a remote.

In other words, I do **NOT** want to obliterate the submodule as directed by the answers to [How do I remove a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1260748/8910547). In fact I wrote this question as a counterpoint to clarify that one.[1]

When I get some time I will try some experiments. It may be as simple as `git submodule deinit` and/or removing its entry from `.gitsubmodules`. I searched Stack Overflow and found no questions or answers addressing this case specifically. Even the superbly written [Mastering Git submodules](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-submodules-34c65e940407) is not clear about this.

---

[1]: The many steps required in those answers tells me that such obliteration is not "normal", otherwise git would include a porcelain command that did it all for you. Instead `git deinit` is provided with very narrow behavior. I think it very intentional.

Comment: Your third bullet-point requirement is the really tricky part. It cannot be guaranteed in any current design, because a submodule repository is not part of its superproject.

Comment: @torek is it tricky for good reason -- i.e. it's an unreasonable requirement in the first place, use subtree or something else?  Or for bad reason: a gap in the design for something that should be handled?

Comment: It's tricky because the original design, as VonC says, assumes that your submodule clone has no value: that it can be thrown away at any time because you can just re-clone it at any time, without losing anything of value. That assumption still lingers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`git submodule deinit` that I documented in 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309) and its associated  `rm -rf .git/modules/a/submodule` both assume the removed submodule was already pushed.

Submodules were initially introduced to be used as read-only, in order to get other repository content into your repository, without necessarily the intent of modifying them.
This [differs from subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31770147/6309), where modifications are more naturally expected.

That being said, yes, if you remove a submodule while having not committed/pushed local changes to said submodule, the end result won't be satisfactory.

A possible patch idea would be to block/fail the git submodule deinit command when it detects that the submodule current HEAD does not match its own internal remote tracking branch (its own `origin/master` for instance)

Comment: Thanks. I ran into this issue where I previously added a third-party library into my project as a submodule so I could make local modifications as needed by the parent project. I didn't use subtree because I saw that solution for own modules, not mods of third party modules (I may be wrong on that). I've since realized node's `package.json` supports local unpublished modules so now do that instead (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61961021/8910547). But I still want to be able to go back to old commit that use the abandoned solution.

Comment: @Inigo I know Christophe's old 2015 article well. But a *lot* has been done on submodule since then.

Comment: @Inigo The `rm` step is necessary when doing a `deinit`. Hence my patch idea, for making Git more robust for your use case.

Comment: It's necessary because of the possibility of adding a different submodule (different repo) at the same path?

Comment: FYI, I'm happy to delete this new question if it makes sense. But I think the original Q and answers need updates/clarifications.

Comment: This new question is important, and should be debated on the Git mailing list: please leave it opened here.

Comment: @Inigo yes, the `rm` step is necessary to ensure a coherent state for the local Git repo (one where the module is no longer referenced)

Comment: I think we may be talking about two different `rm` steps. `rm -rf .git/modules/a/submodule` vs `git rm -f a/submodule`?  Skipping the former I don't believe results in any incoherency. Won't a checkout of past commits make use of it to restore the worktree of the submodule?

Comment: @Inigo that would need to be tested: not sure how Git would react if the internel submodule repo is still there.

Comment: hey @vonc, it's been a year. I've not used submodule since, so haven't thought about this again. Did the debate you mentioned ever happen? I'm inclined to accept your answer at this point.

Comment: @Inigo no debate that I know of for now.