# How to do parallel development on separate repo branches while keeping a common shared base in sync

Tags: git, github, dependency-management, branching-and-merging

I'm developing a product, the code being maintained on github with branch and successive merges on master.

Now, the product has to split into parallel developments: basically I will have two products which share the common base, but each one will evolve separately.

Of course, the common base also will evolve by itself, adding new functionalities and correcting discovered bugs.

A structure will be similar to this one:

```
                /P1--P2--P3--P4---/P5--P6----/P7
master --A--B--C--D--------------E----------F
                   \Q1--Q2--Q3----\Q4--Q5----\Q6
```

So, the question is: if I have two parallel branches, how can I merge them with the changes I'll do to the common baseline (master), without mixing the development of P and Q.

Comment: You should probably merge changes from master branch to other parallel branches regularly.

Comment: `but each one will evolve separately.` Will they have separate history and complete separate products? Maybe go with `git submodule`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether your codebase is monolithic or if the common base can be factored out into a shared library.

### monolithic codebase

If this is a monolithic codebase, and the "common base" cannot be factored out into an independent library, you have a couple of options which I'll describe below.

But in either case, this will require discipline and can get very messy and error prone. This is because any commits you make that mingle changes that belong on `master` (the common base) with changes that only belong to `P` or `Q` will have to manually teased apart and merged to `master`.

##### (A) `master`, `P` and `Q` branches (as you have)

1. You'll maintain a single repo with a branch structure as you show above.
2. The simplest thing to do in terms of commits is to wear three different hats when working: "developer of common base", "developer of P" and "developer of Q". While this is simpler for managing commits and branches, it may be harder for development, as it prevents you from developing common code in `P` or `Q` in an integrated fashion and later moving the common parts into `master`.

   - Checkout the branch for whichever hat you are wearing, make the changes you want to make, and commit them to that branch.
   - After you make changes to the common base `master`, checkout `P` and `git merge` the latest code on `master` into `P`. Do the same for `Q`.
   - If you make a mistake in your hat wearing, and make a change that should be common on the `P` or `Q` branch, see #3.
3. If it's too hard to mentally or physically develop the common base independently of `P` or `Q`, if you need to do it in an integrated fashion, you will pay the price later when you need to tease apart the common parts from the `P` or `Q` parts. Say you make a lot of changes on `P` and you get it working as you want. You will now have to checkout `master` and then `git merge --no-commit P` or `git cherry-pick --no-commit <specific P commits>`, and then weed out the `P`-specific changes before committing to `master` and then merging those changes into `Q`.

##### (B) `master`, `P` and `Q` repos (forks)

This option is essentially the same as (A), except instead of branches you maintain separate repos. You would start with the common base repo, and then fork it twice into `P` and `Q` repos. You'd configure `P` and `Q` to have the common base repo as the `upstream` repo.

If you set `upstream` to point to your local copy of the base repo, you would use `git fetch`, `git pull` and `git push` commands to copy/merge commits from one repo to another.

If you set `upstream` to point to the GitHub copy of the base repo, you can use GitHub's pull request mechanism to push changes you've made in `P` or `Q` to `upstream`.

The difference between #2 and #3 above apply to this scenario as well.

### (C) common base factored into a library

This is the best approach if you can use it. The shared library, P and Q would be developed in separate repos.

You can use one of a number methods to integrate the common library into P and Q. [Package Manager vs. Git Submodule/Subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52256490/package-manager-vs-git-submodule-subtree/61961021#61961021) describes the most common ways to do this using Git: `git submodule`, `git subtree` or the package manager for the language you are coding in.

Once you choose, there are an abundance of resources on the Web or StackOverflow on each of these choices, comparing submodules to subtrees, and how to develop within a "monorepo" if that's what you want to do.

Comment: @Paolo-Di-Pietro would be nice to get feedback on my answer given all the work I  put into it.